# How do I update a non-unique property in Freebase?

Tags: freebase, mqlwrite

I've been working on a [calorie counter](http://wholcomb.github.io/calorie_counter/) and I'm slowly making progress on my MQL write. The issue that I'm having currently is updating the recipe itself which is in the `/common/topic/description` property.

The query that I am using currently is:

```
[{
  id: recipeId, // previously retrieved
  '/common/topic/description': {
    connect: 'replace',
    value: $('#description textarea').val(),
    lang: '/lang/en'
  }
}]
```

This succeeds in executing, but when I [query](http://tinyurl.com/lerqfyg) ([another](http://tinyurl.com/ln4c4h7)) after it has run I get an error:

```
{
  "domain": "global",
  "reason": "invalid",
  "message": "Unique query may have at most one result. Got 2",
  "locationType": "other",
  "location": "/common/topic/description"
}
```

According to [the documentation](http://mql.freebaseapps.com/ch05.html#objectconnection), `connect: replace` does an update on unique properties and an insert on non-unique ones. So am I getting that because a value was inserted?

Is it necessary to remove the other value to prevent the error? Do I need to know the existing value in order to remove it?

```
{
  id: recipeId,
  '/common/topic/description': {
    connect: 'delete',
    value: 'Value currently stored',
    lang: '/lang/en'
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem doesn't anything to do with updating non-unique properties.  Your read query is the issue.  You didn't quote the failing query, but the part of the error message that says `"location": "/common/topic/description"` is your hint.  That topic has two descriptions, one empty and one not, but you haven't used array notation in you query.

This will work:

```
[{
  "id": "/m/0wh83sg",
  "/food/recipe/ingredients": [{
    "id": null,
    "ingredient": {
      "id": null,
      "name": null,
      "/food/food/energy": null,
      "/common/topic/image": {
        "id": null,
        "optional": true,
        "limit": 1
      },
      "optional": true
    },
    "unit": {
      "id": null,
      "name": null,
      "optional": true
    },
    "quantity": null,
    "notes": null
  }],
  "/common/topic/description": [{}]
}]
```

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to retrieve the entries, but when someone updates a recipe I don't want to create a new entry. To do an update do I need to remove the old entry?

Comment: Does "entry" mean a `/common/topic/description` in this context?  Since the description property allows multiple values, yes, you need to delete any obsolete values that you no longer want.